# on Change Event is Not Firing While Typing react-jsonform-schema

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

I am using React Json From Schema NPM but with react-jsonschema-form-extras
when i type new value it goes empty after lost focus. and on change event is firing while typing.

i am using typahead control.

Comment: Usually this is because of multiple react versions running on the page.